# Numpy masked operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am a new python user and I am quite interesting on understanding in depth how works the NumPy module. I am writing on a function able to use both masked and unmasked arrays as data input. 
I have noticed that there are several [numpy masked operations](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.ma.html) that look similar (and even work?) to its normal (unmasked) counterpart. One of such functions is `numpy.zeros` and `numpy.ma.zeros`. Could someone else tell me the advantage of, say, creating an array using `numpy.ma.zeros` vs. `numpy.zeros`? It makes an actual difference when you are using masked arrays? I have noticed that when I use `numpy.zeros_like` it works fine for both creating a masked or unmasked array.

Comment: Why the downvote? I did not find any useful information on the numpy web page about this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.ma.zeros` creates a masked array rather than a normal array which could be useful if some later operation on this array creates invalid values. An example from the manual:

> Arrays sometimes contain invalid or missing data.  When doing
>   operations on such arrays, we wish to suppress invalid values, which
>   is the purpose masked arrays fulfill (an example of typical use is
>   given below).
>
> For example, examine the following array:
>
> ```
> >>> x = np.array([2, 1, 3, np.nan, 5, 2, 3, np.nan])
> ```
>
> When we try to calculate the mean of the data, the result is
>   undetermined:
>
> ```
> >>> np.mean(x) nan
> ```
>
> The mean is calculated using roughly `np.sum(x)/len(x)`, but since
>   any number added to `NaN` produces `NaN`, this doesn't work. 
>   Enter masked arrays:
>
> ```
> >>> m = np.ma.masked_array(x, np.isnan(x))
> >>> m
> masked_array(data = [2.0 1.0 3.0 -- 5.0 2.0 3.0 --],
>       mask = [False False False  True False False False  True],
>       fill_value=1e+20)
> ```
>
> Here, we construct a masked array that suppress all `NaN` values. 
>   We may now proceed to calculate the mean of the other values:
>
> ```
> >>> np.mean(m)
> 2.6666666666666665
> ```

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation. Actually, in my function I used `np.ma.mean` instead `np.mean` because of the reason you have explained. I just was obsessed on understanding the `numpy.ma` class, specifically on creating arrays filled by zeros and ones. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner don't get too bogged down with masked arrays.  It's a subclass of `np.ndarray`,  that is useful when dealing with data that has some bad values that you'd like to ignored when calculating things like the mean.  But otherwise you should focus on creation and indexing (and calculations) with the base numpy class.

Not only is `ma` array a subclass, it contains 2 regular arrays. One has the data, including any 'bad' values.  That is a regular numpy array.  The other is a boolean array, the mask.  The developers of the masked class tried to make it behave in the same ways as the regular arrays, but with this added masking.  Most, if not all, of the added features of masked arrays are implemented in Python code.

It is hard to understand the underlying C code for `numpy`, but it is instructive to look at the functions and methods that are implemented in Python.  I often look at those in an `ipython` session, but they can also be studied on the numpy github repository.

Comment: Thanks for a such instructive comment. I am also learning _indexing_ with `numpy`, since it seems to be a major skill I need to build efficient functions (say, vectorizing). I just got obsessed on trying to understand the 'behind the scenes' of `numpy` arrays. Thanks!